# Turn 1111 into zero

Tags: lateral-thinking, matches

Draw exactly two non-touching straight lines to turn 1111 (as shown below) into zero.

[image: four identical vertical lines side-by-side]

*Note: A minus sign is one line*

Answer (score 30, accepted):

How about this for a solution?

> [image: it spells NIL]

Comment: I thought the non touching part also means no touching the 1111 , does it become easier or something if the 2 lines can touch anything?

Comment: @encryptoferia I interpreted it as the two lines you add can't touch each other, but if it makes you feel better, you can add a little bit of whitespace where my lines touch the existing ones and it'll still read the same

Answer (score 17):

> A minus sign is one line.

Fine.

> [image]
>  Not nearly as nice as juicifer's answer, mind you.

Answer (score 17):

> [image: Solutions]

> `|0|` -> absolute value of 0 is 0

Comment: @Tim it's explained in the second spoiler.

Answer (score 10):

More mathematical then lateral:

> $\overline{11-11}$ (complex conjugate of 0, which equals 0)

Answer (score 10):

Lateral-thinking

> [image: Striked input]

> Just strike through everything you don't need, and what remains is "ZERO".

Comment: you could argue the top is a 5

Answer (score 7):

A very simple solution, without any trick, that doesn't appear to have been proposed yet :

> [image: ii - 1 - 1]

i.e.

> II - I - I
>  The sticks are read as Latin numbers (anyway they don't correspond to any arabic number)

Let's do the maths :

> 2-1-1=0

Comment: I like your solution, but regarding the "they don't correspond to any arabic number" comment, | | sure looks like 11 to me.

Comment: @JasonPatterson I think it's much more common to write 1 with a small diagonal top left strike, but you're right if we consider old-style numerals. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numeral_variations?wprov=sfla1

Answer (score 3):

> Use 2 straight lines to draw an `!` at the beginning of `1111`.

You will get

> !1111

> which, at least, in JavaScript results to `false` but equals (with `==` not `===`) to **0**.

Answer (score 3):

I tried earlier to answer this, realized I was doing basic math wrong, and deleted my answer in a near-fatal bout of self-consciousness.  Attempt #2:

> $11^1 - 11$

NOTE: turns out this is a duplicate of @AxiomaticSystem's answer.

Nothing to see here....

Comment: This answer already exists though (by @AxiomaticSystem).

Comment: @infinitezero, Ah.  I had missed that.  Thanks for the callout.

Answer (score 2):

Have some questionable answers:

Option A (requires $x$):

> Take the second derivative of a constant: [image: option A]

Option B (requires squinting):

> Kind of vaguely the word "NULL": [image: option B]

Answer (score 2):

> [image: Absolute value of -1, minus 1]

Explanation:

> |-1| - 1 = 0

Another one, if we allow different glyphs:

> [image: Absolute value of 1, minus 1]

Answer (score 2):

||| = |

Either 111 = 1, which is false, evaluates to 0 in VAX BASIC;
or Roman numeral III = I, false for the same reason.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

> 1 - 1/1

(padding for minimum 30 characters)

Answer (score 1):

Similar in logic to another solution:

> Boolean Negate:
>  [image: Boolean Negate] 
>  $\lnot 1111$

> Whether the negate is on the first digit or whole expression doesn't matter: 
>  $\lnot (1\cdot1\cdot1\cdot1) = 0$ by Idempotence law 
>  ($\lnot 1)\cdot1\cdot1\cdot1 = 0$ by Annulment law

Answer (score -2):

> Flip the picture sideways and visualise it like a digital alarm clock or a scientific calculator:
>  [image: 1111 Flipped Sideways:]

Comment: How is that a zero? It looks more like some kind of super-8 to me.

Answer (score -3):

How's about:

> | | = | |

Explanation - hopefully this isn't too janky.

> 11 = 11
>  Both sides cancel out and you're left with 0 = 0, or just 0.